# How can I call a Rust function from Go with a slice as a parameter?

Tags: go, rust, ffi

I want to call some external functions written in Rust from Go with a reference to a slice.

I have the following  Rust code:

```rust
extern crate libc;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn callme(data: &mut [libc::c_double]) -> i32 {
    data.len() as i32
}
```

This function is made available for the cgo compiler through this C-style header file:

```c
#IFNDEF BOGUSLIB_H
#DEFINE BOGUSLIB_H

extern int callme(double* data);    

#ENDIF
```

I can now call this function from Go with the Rust crate compiled as a cdylib:

```golang
//#cgo CFLAGS: -Ipath/to/libfolder
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -Lpath/to/libfolder -lboguslib
//#include <boguslib.h>
import "C"
import (
   "unsafe"
   . "fmt"  
)

func CallmeExternal() {
   data := make([]float64, 1, 1)
   data[0] = 1.0
   ptr := (*C.double)(unsafe.Pointer(&data[0]))
   size := C.callme(ptr)

   printf("size %v",size)
}
```

The Go code uses the unsafe pointer trick to access the backing array, since a slice is defined as follows

```golang
type Slice struct {
   data *byte
   uint32 len
   uint32 cap
}
```

When I execute the code above, the length of the passed reference is incredibly large. How do I access the actual data, and what is at this moment being returned?

Comment: In a FFI interface, you really want to stick to types that are understood by the target language. Here, `&mut [...]` is not. Have you checked the [FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/)?

Comment: Great! Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [*The Rust FFI Omnibus*](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/) as [provided by @matthieu-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074919/call-rust-function-from-go-with-slice-as-parameter#comment81098072_47074919), I have successfully rewritten the code. The function signature must accept the types understood by the target language.

The Rust function signature changed to:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn callme(slice: *const libc::c_double, len: libc::size_t) -> libc::c_int {
    let data = slice::from_raw_parts(slice, len as usize);
    data.len() as i32
}
```

The declaration in the header file as follows:

```c
// skip include guards
#include <stdio.h>

extern int callme(double* slice, size_t len);
```

And the call from Go has now changed as well

```golang
func CallmeExternal() {
   data := make([]float64, 2, 2)
   data[0] = 1.0
   ptr := (*C.double)(unsafe.Pointer(&data[0]))
   len := C.size_t(len(data))
   size := C.callme(ptr, len)

   printf("size %v",size)
}
```

This returns `2`.